# Liferay 6.0.5: Limit user login only to his organization

Tags: authentication, organization

I have a site, and I would like to make it "multi-country".
I have created several organizations and users that belongs to one of them.

I'd like to do this: when a user logs in from one organization page, say it MySite/EN/home, how can I prevent it to be logged in also for another organization page, say it MySite/IT/home?

Actually, if a user logs-in in mysite/en/home and visit mysite/it/home, he is logged in also in that page.

Can this be prevented?

Answer (score 0):

Liferay, out-of-box, doesnt permit what you desire, if a user is logged in this is true in every part of the liferay portal.

I try to write some chances you can do:

1st chance)
If each organization has different virtual host setting, the login cookie is only valid for the domain the user logged in.

2nd chance)
A logged user can be organization-member on a organization and a simple user on each others organizations. You can set the permission on different roles to allow different actions and different view level among different organizations for the same user.

3rd chance)
You have to develop new portal extension througth ext-let plugin that can alter the portal behaviour...

bye